# Solana Crypto Retrieval

Tags: transactions, account, wallet, transfer, send-transaction

Recently I sent Solana to the following address:

```
GJRs4FwHtemZ5ZE9x3FNvJ8TMwitKTh21yxdRPqn7npE
```

I sent it from my Coinbase Wallet account, now it has come to my attention that crypto sent CAN NOT be reversed unless I contact the address recipient, but I know that my funds are NOT lost and I’m trying to get my funds back, so I would greatly appreciate it help on this matter!

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned in your post, a transfer of funds cannot be reversed. Only the holder of the authority for the wallet `GJRs4FwHtemZ5ZE9x3FNvJ8TMwitKTh21yxdRPqn7npE` can release funds from the wallet.

If you know the holder of the wallet authority then you can contact them and explain your situation, a tool such as [FoxyDing](https://famousfoxes.com/ding) will allow you to send a message to the wallet too.

I'm sorry there is not much else you can do in this situation and it is best to assume your funds are lost to that wallet.

We all make mistakes, so moving forward it is best to always ensure you:

- Double check the wallet you are sending funds to
- Double check your transaction before submitting
- Never manually enter a wallet address
- Send a small test amount to the wallet you want to transfer funds to, especially if this is the first time you are interacting with that wallet

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that transactions on blockchains aren't reversible. Always make sure you see what address you are sending funds to. Nothing can be done in this situation unfortunately :(